# Trying to connect to access database with PDO

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I am trying to connect to access database that I have on the c drive. I uncommented access extension pdo in INI file. I ran the driver test and it shows odbc driver is installed. I am using wamp with apache  server but I keep getting this error

SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

```html
<?php
    try {
      $conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\\staffing.mdb;Uid=Admin");

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it this way should work.

```
<?php
try {

 $conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\\staffing.mdb;Uid=Admin");

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: I will try It write now. Thank you

Comment: Thank you it worked I was able to connect no errors.