# How to connect to MS Access database in PHP7?

Tags: php, ms-access

I'm using WampServer and PHP7. I'm trying to connect to a MS Access database that I created and named **"db_operation.accdb"**. I moved that database to **`"C:\wamp\www\Operation-Monitor\db"`**. I can't seem to figure out how to connect to it. Although, I can perfectly see it when I browse **`"127.0.0.1\Operation-Monitor\db"`**. However, I'm clueless about connecting it.

```
    $mysql_user = "";
    $mysql_password = "";
    $mysql_database = "127.0.0.1\\Operation-Monitor\\db\\db_operation.accdb";

    $db = odbc_connect("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$mysql_database;Persist Security Info=False;", $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die ("Couldn't find any databases.");
```

I'm getting the following error when I execute my code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SximI.png
[image]

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.uodbc.php
???
https://www.sitepoint.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/

Comment: Answers to the question can you found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066516/microsoft-access-with-php-and-pdo and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858847/trying-to-connect-to-access-database-with-pdo

Comment: @НиколайЛубышев I've already read the documentation. I'm still not sure on how to do it.

Comment: @jspit I already read those questions. They use PDO. I prefer to stay away from PDO.

Comment: im not shure, but ... $mysql_database its realy must have NET address like a 127.0.0.1 but a somthing like "C:/..."  or "/var/www/..." ?
Real path, but not NET adress ??

Comment: And where is $mysql_database is used?

Comment: And you are must determine the datasorce name .. somewhere .. in windows system?

Comment: @НиколайЛубышев It's the localhost address. If I wanna access `index.php`, then I can access it with this URL `"127.0.0.1/Operation-Monitor/index.php"`.

Comment: $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mysql_database", $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
???

Comment: @НиколайЛубышев Nope. That doesn't work. Either because my database extension is .accdb OR the odbc is different.

Comment: PHP has a COM bridge from where you can call a VBA macro. Might be better to export the acess stuff and migrate to mysql or postgress. Then you can do the opposite way more easy way by odbc or a native connector.

Comment: @ThomasLudewig I'll tell you what I need. I simply need an easy movable database. Why? Because I don't have an SQL Server and that is the limitation that I'd have to find a solution for. Any tip would help, my friend.

Comment: Ok Then take a look at sqlite. There are also native vba bindings for. And best you can easy address sqlite with php office .net ...and so on. The whole database is in a single file - more easy moveable and more compatible is nearly not possible. You can even run sqlite inside a browser with JS if you want. I use this often for internal tools for exat those reasons. There are also a lot of free GUIs for. But back to your problem.Did you check you paths ? There are \ / differences and php needs a server path usually. Not the FS path.

Comment: @ThomasLudewig I actually had SQLite in mind, but because I had no experience with it, I chose to ignore it. I heard it was the best choice for local databases. So, I will look into it. As for my problem. I even tried a normal Windows full path to the file inside the `file_exists();` function and confirmed that PHP can successfully read it. Then I realized that it is an odbc driver issue NOT a connection issue. Anyways, SQLite seems like the easiest way out. I'll do my research I guess. Thank you for coming by, Thomas. I'll still come back to you in here...

Comment: @ThomasLudewig Yup. I used SQLite. I had to do a research though and run some tests on it. It worked! Please write an answer suggesting that I should use SQLite and I will mark your answer as the solution. Thank you.

Comment: No problem you are welcome. I am also very happy with SQLITE . It might not be the solution for heavy multi user usage or if you want tow write SQL programs . But there are a lot cases where it is not needed or wanted. In this cases it really becomes very handy. That is the reason why a lot of application suse it internally. Some video or music players. In my autocad i use it to store 3d coordinates from a surveyor. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a seamless *portable* database storage which works with office products as well as server based i suggest to  have  a look at SQLITE. The database is inside a single file which makes it highly portable between devices. It is open source, supportetd on many OS and has working connectors foe nearly anything possible. In your case you can have for example a fast ado connector in the WAMP server and on Excel and friends a native VBA connector.