# Using PDO_ODBC in PhpStorm

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

emphasized textI am doing a project that the main goal is through PHP get an application that reads from an Microsoft Access a database and then shows some content of some tables.
I am trying to use PDO_ODBC to get the connection but i can't seem to get it to work and i don't know how to make it work.
I followed an example code that should make the connection but it won't.

```
<?php
$bits = 4 * PHP_INT_SIZE;
echo "(Info: This script is running as $bits-bit.)\r\n\r\n";

print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());

$connStr =
    'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' .
    'Dbq=c:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\LabSid\\exemplo1.mdb';


try {
    $dbh = new PDO($connStr);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "NEW:" .$e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT marca FROM carros" ;

try {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "PREPARE:" . $e->getMessage();
}

// query parameter value(s)
$params = array(
    5,
    'Homer'
);

try {
    $sth->execute($params);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "EXECUTE:" .$e->getMessage();
}

try {
    while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {
        echo $row['marca'] . "\r\n";
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "FETCH:" .$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

This is the debug line

> (Info: This script is running as 32-bit.)
>
> Array (
> [0] => MySQL
> [1] => odbc
> [2] => pgsql
> [3] => sqlite )
> NEW:SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][Gestor de controladores de ODBC] The name of the data
> source was not found and not specified in any controller
> predefinidoPHP Notice:  Undefined variable: dbh in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\www\index.php on line 24 PHP Fatal error:
> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\www\index.php:24 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\www\index.php on line 24
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\www\index.php
> on line 24 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
> prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\www\index.php:24 Stack
> trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\www\index.php on line 24 Process finished with exit code 255

Comment: This is your actual code? What error message if any and on what line? Show debugger details.

Comment: Just added the debug code at the bottom

Comment: From what I read, doesn't like variable dbh and function prepare() is getting a null it can't handle. Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858847/trying-to-connect-to-access-database-with-pdo